# Mount a drive partition last accessed by Windows

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

Comrades, I believe I've made a horrible mistake.

I've got a nice desktop that I decided to switch to Ubuntu from Windows 8, and I created a backup folder of all my digital valuables. Because my desktop has two drives (an ssd for the operating system and and a Terabyte drive for who knows what...) I thought it would be smooth to save my backup folder to the terabyte drive, install Ubuntu on the ssd, wiping windows in the process, and then finally copy the files (or at least mount the dang partition) in Ubuntu afterward.

I bet you think I ran into a problem... (You'd be right)
[Error Message!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTQjV.png)

Whenever I see 'non-zero exit value' its usually something I can never figure out. How am I going to be able to get my drive mounted or otherwise retreive my data?

Thanks in advance for any help

Update: I can get into the partition within the terminal, but when I try to move something, the terminal blanks out until I ^C.

Updated: After First Suggestion - post lsblk

lsblk output at Drive:

```
the1jonbrown@jon-desktop:/media/the1jonbrown/202A29DD2A29B128$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 223.6G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0 223.6G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0 931.2G  0 part /media/the1jonbrown/202A29DD2A29B128
sdg      8:96   0 465.8G  0 disk 
└─sdg1   8:97   0 465.8G  0 part 
sdh      8:112  1  14.9G  0 disk 
└─sdh1   8:113  1  14.9G  0 part /media/the1jonbrown/76EA6AB3EA6A6F75
sdi      8:128  1  29.1G  0 disk 
└─sdi1   8:129  1  29.1G  0 part /media/the1jonbrown/JONBROWN
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Updated: After 2nd Suggestion - sudo ntfsfix stb1

Thanks for all of the assistance everyone!
I tried the ntfsfix but it said no such file or directory, here's an ls and my attempt:

```
    the1jonbrown@jon-desktop:/dev$ ls
    autofs           i2c-5               rtc0      tty2   tty55      ttyS31
    block            i2c-6               sda       tty20  tty56      ttyS4
    bsg              i2c-7               sda1      tty21  tty57      ttyS5
    btrfs-control    i2c-8               sdb       tty22  tty58      ttyS6
    bus              i2c-9               sdb1      tty23  tty59      ttyS7
    cdrom            initctl             sdc       tty24  tty6       ttyS8
    cdrw             input               sdd       tty25  tty60      ttyS9
    char             kfd                 sde       tty26  tty61      uhid
    console          kmsg                sdf       tty27  tty62      uinput
    core             kvm                 sdg       tty28  tty63      urandom
    cpu              lightnvm            sdg1      tty29  tty7       usb
    cpu_dma_latency  log                 sg0       tty3   tty8       userio
    cuse             loop0               sg1       tty30  tty9       v4l
    disk             loop1               sg2       tty31  ttyprintk  vcs
    dri              loop2               sg3       tty32  ttyS0      vcs1
    drm_dp_aux0      loop3               sg4       tty33  ttyS1      vcs2
    dvd              loop4               sg5       tty34  ttyS10     vcs3
    dvdrw            loop5               sg6       tty35  ttyS11     vcs4
    ecryptfs         loop6               sg7       tty36  ttyS12     vcs5
    fb0              loop7               shm       tty37  ttyS13     vcs6
    fd               loop-control        snapshot  tty38  ttyS14     vcsa
    full             mapper              snd       tty39  ttyS15     vcsa1
    fuse             mcelog              sr0       tty4   ttyS16     vcsa2
    hidraw0          media0              stderr    tty40  ttyS17     vcsa3
    hidraw1          mem                 stdin     tty41  ttyS18     vcsa4
    hidraw2          memory_bandwidth    stdout    tty42  ttyS19     vcsa5
    hidraw3          mqueue              tty       tty43  ttyS2      vcsa6
    hpet             net                 tty0      tty44  ttyS20     vfio
    hugepages        network_latency     tty1      tty45  ttyS21     vga_arbiter
    hwrng            network_throughput  tty10     tty46  ttyS22     vhci
    i2c-0            null                tty11     tty47  ttyS23     vhost-net
    i2c-1            port                tty12     tty48  ttyS24     vhost-    vsock
    i2c-10           ppp                 tty13     tty49  ttyS25     video0
    i2c-11           psaux               tty14     tty5   ttyS26     zero
    i2c-12           ptmx                tty15     tty50  ttyS27
    i2c-13           pts                 tty16     tty51  ttyS28
    i2c-2            random              tty17     tty52  ttyS29
    i2c-3            rfkill              tty18     tty53  ttyS3
    i2c-4            rtc                 tty19     tty54  ttyS30
    the1jonbrown@jon-desktop:/dev$ sudo ntfsfix stb1
    Failed to determine whether stb1 is mounted: No such file or directory
    Mounting volume... Failed to access 'stb1': No such file or directory
    Error opening 'stb1': No such file or directory
    FAILED
    Attempting to correct errors... Failed to access 'stb1': No such file or directory
    Error opening 'stb1': No such file or directory
    FAILED
    Failed to startup volume: No such file or directory
    Failed to access 'stb1': No such file or directory
    Error opening 'stb1': No such file or directory
    Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
```

And the thing is, it's [technically mounted, right?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyD9y.png) Before, when I went to Additional Partition Options -> Edit FileSystem then renamed the partition, thats when I got the error message in the original post above.

I think I have a boot disk I can use if I need to, I'm looking into that as well.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: please post the output of  `lsblk`

Comment: I edited the post.

Comment: have you tried mounting `sdg1`?

Comment: Looks like this problem occured due to Window's fast start up which is in deed a kind of hibernation. Try `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1` in a terminal and try to mount again. If that does not help, you would have to reinstall Windows to shut it down properly or use a live CD like Hiren's Boot CD to repair the file system. Generally it is better to avoid using NTFS partitions if we don't have Windows installed because we would always run in problems if the file system gets corrupted and Windows tools are required to repair the damage.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to turn off hibernation or fastboot in Windows. Because you don't have Windows installed the only other option is [`ntfsfix`](https://itsfoss.com/solve-ntfs-mount-problem-ubuntu-windows-8-dual-boot/):

To summarize the article, use the command:

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdXY
```

Where `sdXY` is the Windows locked down partition.